# Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving the error of `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`.

It appears that it is because of this code

```
const LoginAuth = () => {
  navigate(routes.INDEX);
  return null;
};
```

removing `navigate(routes.INDEX);` stops the error.

**What is wrong with the code? Should I be using another method to redirect an `authUser`?** Any help is appreciated.

It is a part of

```
import React from 'react';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

import AuthUserContext from './AuthUserContext';
import withAuthentication from './withAuthentication';

import Layout from './Layout';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';    
import * as routes from '../../constants/routes';

const LoginAuth = () => {
  navigate(routes.INDEX);
  return null;
};

const LoginPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Transition>
      <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        {authUser => (authUser ? <LoginAuth /> : <LoginNonAuth />)}
      </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    </Transition>
  </Layout>
);

const LoginNonAuth = () => <LoginForm />;

export default withAuthentication(LoginPage);
```

Comment: Your LoginAuth is a function that should return additional stuff to render to the page and you call navigate directly in it. Are you trying to navigate as soon as the component is rendered?

Comment: Hey @rory_za. Yes, if the `authUser` is authenticated the page renders `LoginAuth`, else `LoginNonAuth` is rendered. Therefore, if the user authenticates using the `<LoginForm />` or is currently authenticated, the user is **immediately** redirected (`naviagate()`) to another page.

Comment: It possibly can be solved by putting side effects (`navigate`) into `componentDidMount`. Please, let know if this works.

Comment: Hey @estus. Yes, wrapping in a `stateful` container with `navigate` in `componentDidMount` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @estus. If you wanted to add to an answer, I'll accept. If not, I'll do so - thought you may want the reputation points.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've got enough rep but hope this will help somebody else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stateless functional components are expected to be pure functions, i.e. contain no side effects, while `navigate()` provides side effects.

Side effects are supposed to be applied after the component is mounted, that's the purpose of `componentDidMount` hook.

It should be:

```
class LoginAuth extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    navigate(routes.INDEX);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

With the introduction of stateful functional components, side effects belong to `useEffect` hook:

```
const LoginAuth = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(routes.INDEX);
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problme is before mount the component history.push is called here. I realized after that and used useEffect inside the logic then it working without any issue.

**Error:**

```
const Component = ({
    classes,
    isAuthenticated
}) => {

    const history = useHistory()


    if (isAuthenticated === true) {
        history.push(DASHBOARD_ROUTE)
    }

    return null
}
```

**Solution:**

```
const Component = ({
    classes,
    isAuthenticated
}) => {

    const history = useHistory()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated === true) {
            history.push(DASHBOARD_ROUTE)
        }
    }, [])

    return null
}
```