# how to redirect to "/" by using useHistory in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check data.code.
if data.code = true, rendering Page.
else, go to "/".

so i use usehistory() but it dosen't work.
error is that
Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Table, Container, Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Menu from "../Menu/index";


export default ({ loading, data }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  if (loading === true) {
    return <Loader></Loader>;
  } else if (!loading && data.code) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu></Menu>
        <Container style={{ marginTop: "7em" }}>
          <Table singleLine>
            <Table.Header>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.HeaderCell>번호</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>제목</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>글쓴이</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>등록일</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>조회수</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>추천</Table.HeaderCell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>
            <Table.Body>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123888888888888888888</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Body>
          </Table>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (!data.code) {
    history.push("/");
  }
};
```

Comment: See this stack overflow question. It might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912238/render-methods-should-be-a-pure-function-of-props-and-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try checking the data.code inside `useEffect`:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Table, Container, Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Menu from "../Menu/index";
import { useEffect } from "react";


export default ({ loading, data }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    if(data && !data.code) history.push("/")
  }, [data])

  if (loading === true) {
    return <Loader></Loader>;
  }
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu></Menu>
        <Container style={{ marginTop: "7em" }}>
          <Table singleLine>
            <Table.Header>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.HeaderCell>번호</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>제목</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>글쓴이</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>등록일</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>조회수</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>추천</Table.HeaderCell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>
            <Table.Body>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123888888888888888888</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>123</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Body>
          </Table>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: No problem, make sure to accept/vote the answer if it helped you :) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Another option you have is to use the `Redirect` component to handle the redirection, something like the following:

Documentation: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Table, Container, Loader } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Menu from "../Menu/index";
import { useEffect } from "react";


export default ({ loading, data }) => {
  // If you want to keep the redirect in the history stack
  // use the push prop on Redirect
  if (!loading && !data.code) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
};
```